# HTML JQUERY ==> Previous parent div

Tags: jquery, html

Sample HTML code

```
//Not the correct working code just wrote for this clarification

    <div id="1">
    <input type="text">
    .
    .
    <p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
    <button id="btn1">
    <button id="btn2">
    .
    .
    .

    </div>
```

On a Button Click i need to navigate to

in  ID 1

What i got is

`$(this).parent().prev().parent()` i can reach to  ID 1.

Am looking for alternative method to reach the  with ID1 and accessing their elements from Button click on  ID2

Am not sure if am repeating but just want to know the alternative ways of doing it !!

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some more HTML code please? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: If you know ID, why you not get element by ID directly?

Comment: This question needs clarification. The title suggests one thing, while the overly simplified example suggest something else. In its current state you will get different answers that solve entirely different use cases, so please provide some clarification. Also start ids with a letter for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Id's are unique, so the answer is simple:

```
$('#1')
```

otherwise it would be:

```
$(this).closest('div').prev('div')
```

Comment: ids might be randomly generated in his case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not correct, it should be:

```
$(this).parent().prev()
```

Without more information about your HTML, I don't think there's any alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$(this).closest('div').prev().find('input').val()
```

Check sample on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vgmce/